URL rewrite is not functioning in Apache Server properly
We are experiencing an issue with a URL rewrite that is not functioning correctly.
The rule is as follows:
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https://%{HTTP_HOST}/xx/xxx#/login" [R=301,L]
However, the URL is being rewritten to https://xxx.xx.xx.xx/xxx/xxx%23/xxx, where the '#' is incorrectly replaced by '%23', which the application does not accept.
we cannot really do anything else e.g. change the url on the application side

Since the hashpound is a special character, you need to specify that you don't want to escape it, like the manual says:

RewriteRule "^/anchor/(.+)" "/bigpage.html#$1" [NE,R]
The above example will redirect /anchor/xyz to /bigpage.html#xyz. Omitting the [NE] will result in the # being converted to its hexcode equivalent, %23, which will then result in a 404 Not Found error condition.

So, you just need to change your rule to this:
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https://%{HTTP_HOST}/xx/xxx#/login" [R=301,L,NE]

